# Transformation?

Tags: transformation

> Yesterday the inspector asked me: “So, when did you last meet Jane?”
> Yesterday the inspector asked me when
> ________________________________last.

I can't think of anything different than "when the last time that I met Jane was" but it doesn't fit in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*last* (3)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/last) is an adverb here.

> Yesterday the inspector asked me when **I saw/met Jane last**.

However, I'd change the order

> Yesterday the inspector asked me when I **last saw/met Jane**.